# google firebase not returning data from a collection ref?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm creating a reference hook to a "products" table in a Google Firebase db like this:

```
  var productsRef = firebase.database().ref("products");
```

However, I'm having problems getting the data.  For example, this type of pattern seems fairly common for data access in Firebase:

```
productsRef.on('value', function(snapshot) {
  console.log('snapshot.val()', snapshot.val());
})
```

In the example above, null is written to the console.  What do you recommend as next steps to debug?  The firebase db does have a products collection with records.  This is what my db structure looks like:

inventory-c9076 > Products

- 0

  - Id: 1
  - Name: "my-prod-1"
  - Price: 19.99
- 1

  - Id: 2
  - Name: "my-prod-2"
  - Price: 39.99

Comment: What is the structure of your database? What read permissions does the client have?

Comment: "Your security rules are defined as public, anyone can read or write to your database"

Comment: And you're using the Realtime Database and not Cloud Firestore? I know it seems like a silly question but you said "collection" so I just want to be sure.

Comment: I updated my original post to include the db structure

Comment: @Jen thanks for your help.  I'm brand new to Firebase.  This is described as a "Database" on firebase.google.com

Comment: this is a "Realtime Database" as opposed to a "Cloud Firestore"

Comment: it's interesting that I can set the "products" reference to "products2" (which doesn't exist) in my code above and the promise code is still entered.  is there some type of error handler I can include to get error details or does google not return any error details for this scenario, which would seem strange?

Comment: Your code spells `products`, while your sample data spells `Products` (with an uppercase `P`). Firebase is case-sensitive, so make sure that they're the same.

Comment: case-sensitivity was the problem. thanks frank!